# Export multiple groups in photoshop to different photos for web! Each group in Photoshop is a photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, save, actions, actionscript

I dont know how to export multiple files for web (JPG) without having to press all the time the same thing File--> Export--> Save for Web... I could use the quick export which has the option to save groups with their names in JPG but I need to have optimized files for web! This is an image for you to see and understand better[image: I want from each group a single optimised image for web save in a specific folder while each file is named with the name of specific group]
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried recording an action?

Comment: I don't know what to exactly record in the action for it to be correct

Comment: Just record File > Export > Save for web, then follow through the process to save one image. Then stop the action.  Then you can just play the action each time you want to save.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your quick export preferences.

> Change Quick Export preferences
>
> By default, Quick Export generates assets as PNG with transparency and
>   prompts you every time to select an export location. You can change
>   these settings by selecting either Preferences > Export or File >
>   Export > Export Preferences and then specifying the following:
>
> Your preferred format for Quick Export: PNG, JPG, PNG-8, GIF, or SVG
>   Format-specific parameters. For example, for PNG, you can specify if
>   you want to export assets with Transparency enabled (32-bit) or export
>   smaller-sized images (8-bit). Location for images exported using Quick
>   Export. To do so, select one of the following: Ask Where To Export
>   Each Time: Prompts you to select a location every time you export
>   assets Export Files To An Assets Folder Next To The Current Document:
>   Places the image asset in a subfolder named Assets within the folder
>   containing the source Photoshop document.
>
> Whether you want to include metadata—copyright and contact info—in the
>   exported assets Whether you want to convert the assets to the sRGB
>   color space

[Taken from the adobe help article.](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html)

You also can install a wonderful extension panel that will create quick save buttons for you.

[image]

[Described in this article.](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/what-happened-to-save-for-web-in-photoshop-cc-2015)